# Iterating through all df column pairs and counting non-zero intersections

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a ~15000*1000 dataframe, where each column represents an individual, and each row represents the incidence of a trait (0 or 1).

I want to efficiently compare all pairs of columns, and generate a comma separated list of all mutual traits (row names) for all possible pairs.

Currently, I am looping through all the columns via combn, and pasting mutual row names into a string. That's to say I have a solution, however, it is very, very slow (probably quadratic with column number).

Is there a way to vectorise this problem/approach it with tidyr/dplyr etc.? I can't seem to find a way.

For example:

```
------|individual1 | individual2 | individual3 | ...
trait1|     0      |     1       |      1      | ...
trait2|     0      |     0       |      0      | ...
trait3|     1      |     1       |      1      | ...
 ...  |    ...     |    ...      |     ...     | ...
```

Yields the string `trait1,trait3` for the pair `individual 2` and `individual 3`.

Thanks!

---

Toy data (the actual data is too sparse just to pull a subset):

```
df <- data.frame(trait = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), ind1 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1), ind2 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), ind3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: My bad - 'individual2' and 'individual3' share 'trait1' and 'trait3' (I'll make the edit...)

Comment: Can you provide some data? Just provide few rows and column.

Comment: Added some toy data to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply a custom function on each combination of columns. Maybe the efficiency can be improved a little.

```
t(combn(1:(ncol(df)-1), 2, function(x){
  string <- paste(df$trait[df[[x[1]+1]] == 1 & df[[x[2]+1]] == 1], collapse = ",")
  c(names(df)[x+1], string)
}))

#      [,1]    [,2]      [,3]   
# [1,] "Alice" "Bob"     "c,e"  
# [2,] "Alice" "Charlie" "c,e"  
# [3,] "Bob"   "Charlie" "a,c,e"
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(trait = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                 Alice = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 Bob = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                 Charlie = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this entirely works - in the toy dataset, no pairs of individuals actually share trait `d` (which here is called `trait4`). I've fixed this by changing `which(df[[x[1]+1]] == df[[x[2]+1]])` to `which(df[[x[1]+1]] == 1 &  df[[x[2]+1]] == 1)`. Would it be possible to amend your output to actually include the column and row names e.g. `ind1` instead of `1`, `a` instead of `trait1` etc.?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the rule. Please check my edit.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works really well and is far more elegant and efficient! One final point - supposing my individuals aren't named systematically, e.g. in the original df, `ind1` is called `Alice`, `ind2` is called `Bob` and `ind3` is called `Charlie` - is there a way to amend your code to adjust for this change?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has an accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60468831/3817004), I would like to suggest a different approach which uses `dplyr` and `tidyr` as well as a `data.table` variant.

Whenever column names are treated as data items this indicates that the dataset is stored in an untidy format, IMHO. Reshaping the data into long format will allow to apply the usual data manipulations like joining, grouping, aggregating.

#### `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!"trait") %>% 
  filter(value == 1L) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  inner_join(., ., by = "trait") %>% 
  filter(name.x < name.y) %>% 
  group_by(name.x, name.y) %>% 
  summarise(traits = toString(trait)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   name.x name.y  traits 
>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
> 1 Alice  Bob     c, e   
> 2 Alice  Charlie c, e   
> 3 Bob    Charlie a, c, e
> ```

#### Explanation

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!"trait") %>% 
  filter(value == 1L)
```

reshapes the data into long format which is compact representation of the original matrix in wide format:

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
>    trait name    value
>    <fct> <chr>   <dbl>
>  1 a     Bob         1
>  2 a     Charlie     1
>  3 b     Alice       1
>  4 c     Alice       1
>  5 c     Bob         1
>  6 c     Charlie     1
>  7 d     Charlie     1
>  8 e     Alice       1
>  9 e     Bob         1
> 10 e     Charlie     1
> ```

The `value` column is dropped as it is no longer needed. Then, the long data is joined with itself to find all names which match on `trait`. The result includes pairs of names which are given in a different order, e.g., (Alice, Bob) and (Bob, ALice) as well as duplicates names, e.g., (Bob, Bob). These are removed.

Finally, the data are grouped and summarised.

#### data.table

The `data.table` variant implements the same approach but has the advantage to allow for a *non-equi self-join* which reduces the number of rows directly in the join instead of a subsequent filtering step.

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "trait", variable.name = "name")[value == 1]
long[long, on = .(trait, name < name), .(name1 = x.name, name2 = i.name, trait), nomatch = NULL][
  , .(traits = toString(trait)), keyby = .(name1, name2)]
```

> ```
>    name1   name2  traits
> 1: Alice     Bob    c, e
> 2: Alice Charlie    c, e
> 3:   Bob Charlie a, c, e
> ```